# Servlet does not show any error, but also it's not showing any output

Tags: java, servlets

I'm creating a login page application with JSP servlet and MySQL database. But my application does not show any error.

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String un=request.getParameter("user");
        String pw=request.getParameter("pass");

        // Connect to mysql(mariadb) and verify username password

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // loads driver
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mylogin?" + "username=root&password="); // gets a new connection

            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("select usernmae,password from login where username=? and password=?");
            ps.setString(1, un);
            ps.setString(2, pw);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("invalid user");
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Various login/security functionality is already implemented in Java. You should read about JDBC realm for your application server (e.g. Tomcat: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JDBCRealm) and how to congiure security in your web application (container managed security via web.xml may be the easiest way).

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Is the code above ever executed?

Comment: 1)  There is an obvious typo in the SQL.  2) Have you checked the server-side log files?

Comment: i already debug it.but everything is fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the server side logs? There seems to be a typo in your SQL statement. You can also try to remove the `return` statements in your code.